# I'm a beginner need guidance which software needs to be learnt to be an expert in vba automation

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, vbscript

I'm a finance person want to automate things what we do in Excel and Outloook.

Guide me, what language I need to learn to be a VBA expert.

Br
Uday

Comment: To be a VBA expert, you  need to learn the VB language.

Comment: do you want to use vba to add functionality to your apps or to test the functionality/information within them?

Comment: Br Uday, your question seems to answer itself. Read it carefully!

Comment: VBA is the language. But VBA is not the simplest language for beginners - Python is widely considered as best language for beginner programmers. Programmers as a rule know multiple languages and use the best tool for each job at hand.

Answer (score 1):

VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) *is* the language. There are plenty of free resources on the internet for learning VBA, Google "VBA for beginners" to get you started.